# nodejs + multer + angularjs for uploading without redirecting

Tags: angularjs, node.js, multer

I am using Nodejs + Multer +angularjs for uploading files on the server.
i have a simple HTML file:

```
<form action="/multer" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="photo" name="photo"/> 
<button id="Button1">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Nodejs part:

```
var multer  = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

app.post('/multer', upload.single('photo'), function (req, res) {
    res.end("File uploaded.");
});
```

**this works perfectly** and the file is successfully uploaded. 
but this redirect me to "/multer" after uploading the file (because of the form element).
**How do i stay on the same page??**..possibly using angularjs
so i tried this:

making a HTML angular file:

```
<section data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="file" id="photo" name="photo"/> 
<button id="Button1" ng-click="f()">Upload</button>
</section>
```

and a Angularjs controller:

```
angular.module('users').controller('myCtrl',[$scope,function($scope){
    $scope.f=function(){
        var photo = document.getElementById('photo');
        var file = photo.files[0];
        if (file) {

            //code to make a post request with a file object for uploading?????

            //something like..
            //$http.post('/multer', file).success(function(response) {
            //console.log("success");
            //});
        }
    }
}]);
```

**CAN SOMEONE HELP ME WITH THE CODE FOR MAKING A POST REQUEST WITH A FILE OBJECT FOR UPLOADING USING MULTER FROM ANGULARJS CONTROLLER ?**


thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @SimranKaur yes i found a solution:)

Comment: @SimranKaur I have posted the answer

Comment: hi @GauravGupta I stuck in same kind of problem. Please assist me to save my time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Angularjs directive:

```
angular.module('users').directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Angular html file:

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile"/><br><br>
<button ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
```

Angularjs Controller:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){

        var file = $scope.myFile;
        var uploadUrl = "/multer";
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);

        $http.post(uploadUrl,fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
          console.log("success!!");
        })
        .error(function(){
          console.log("error!!");
        });
    };
```

Nodejs server route file:

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname+ '-' + Date.now()+'.jpg')
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/multer', upload.single('file'));
```

Enjoy!

Comment: for this, "fd.append('file', file)" and, this "upload.single('file')" – big thanks!

Comment: Gives me {Error: Not Found: POST /multer in the terminal and POST XHR https://..../multer  [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 220ms] in the explorer debugger how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you tell me where this Nodejs server route file code will be adding because I am new in angularjs and I am not able to understand this part .

Comment: @nolags try keeping the changes in app.js at the beginning, just after you define app. Mostly you have it after your error handler.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Successfully integrated in a project generated based on Angular-Fullstack-Generator with Yeoman
Adding it in the controller of the related API

Comment: how to do multiple files upload in angular using the same code?