# ng-switch causing error in uploading

Tags: angularjs, node.js, file-upload, ng-switch

I used the answer in this link [nodejs + multer + angularjs for uploading without redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957006/nodejs-multer-angularjs-for-uploading-without-redirecting/34205893#34205893)
for making file uploads in angularjs.
This works perfectly.

According to my requirements i edited the code of angular html file (added ng-switch):

```
<div ng-switch="MyVar">

    <div ng-switch-when="car">
        <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
        <button ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="dog">
        dog
    </div>
</div>
```

All the other files are exactly same.

ng-switch works correctly.

But after this change my file upload wont work (causes server error because no file gets send).
I mean if i remove the switch part as in the link then it works fine.

$scope.myFile shows null even after selecting a file.

Why is ng-switch causing problem?

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ng-switch makes its own scope.  Try using `file-model="$parent.myFile"`.  This question is probably related: [angularjs - ng-switch does not bind ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593299/angularjs-ng-switch-does-not-bind-ng-model?rq=1)