# Skip the upload button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, file-upload, angularjs-directive

I have a `mean-stack` application. I want to implement a button by which users could upload a thumbnail image. I have followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34205893/702977), which works.

However, I want to skip the `upload` button: users click on the `Choose file` button, choose a local file, then I want the file to be uploaded **automatically** without having to click on the `upload` button. The [existing code](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cj6nyTqFsR3OP66r06ts?p=preview) uses a directive to control the `input`, I don't know how to modify that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="file" file-model="myFile" />
  <button ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.uploadFile = function() {
        // $scope.myFile is available here
        alert("uploadFile");
      }
    }]);

    angular.module('app').directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
          var modelSetter = model.assign;

          element.bind('change', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
          });
        }
      };
    }]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to modify the code and achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By accident, I realise adding just one line `scope.uploadFile()` does the trick:

```
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.uploadFile = function() {
        // $scope.myFile is available here
        alert("uploadFile");
      }
    }]);

    angular.module('app').directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
          var modelSetter = model.assign;

          element.bind('change', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
            scope.uploadFile() // works
          });
        }
      };
    }]);
  </script>
```